# Remote Desktop Windows 7 into a XP sp3 system print issue

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have a windows 7 laptop that I use to remote in to work, which is a XP sp3. I have a brother MFC-8670dn printer. I have the win7 print drivers installed and working on the win7. I made local printers accessible over the RDP. I installed the xp drivers for the Brother printer. So my question is, " Is there a way that I can print from my win7 machine remotely connected to a xp sp3 system"? Or is there no way that I can put the correct drivers on the xp machine to have it redirect to my laptop(win7)

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, but unless there is a platform difference (x64 v x86) I don't think you actually need to install the drivers on to both machines, only the printer host.

Next time you launch remote desktop, make sure to tick the `Printers` option under `Local resources`, and it should automatically configure itself.
[image]